# How can I select an element using JQuery and modify it's contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="button">
<a href="/" target="_blank" class="test">Photos</a>
</div>
```

Using JQuery how can I select .button and remove the target="_blank" from the html?

I was able to get to here by following the JQuery docs but i am new and lost.

```
$('.button').html("<a href="/" class="test">Photos</a>");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(".button a").removeAttr("target");
```

Although this is easy enough to figure out what this does, the removeAttr() method will remove any/all html attributes that's called from the selector.

**Here's the documentation**: http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/

Comment: its always better to tell the reason for the code fail to a new learner

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
I have changed href value for testing.
Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pZAdP/8/

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.button').html("<a href='/go' class='test'>Photos</a>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:  You are using double quote for quoting html and tag both use `**single quote**` for one of them

**Solution**:

```
$('.button').html('<a href="/" class="test">Photos</a>');
```

and if you want to remove *just a attribute* use this

```
$('.button').find('a').removeAttr('target');
```